# JPanel will not redraw until mouseover?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

```
public double giveTest()
  {
    int correct = 0;
    int incorrect = 0;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test: " + stuName);
    frame.setSize(700, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    for(int x = 0; x < doneTest.length; x ++)
    {
      frame.setVisible(false);
      int pressed;

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      JLabel question = new JLabel(doneTest[x][0]);

      JButton button1 = new JButton();
      button1.setText(doneTest[x][1]);
      JButton button2 = new JButton();
      button2.setText(doneTest[x][2]);
      JButton button3 = new JButton();
      button3.setText(doneTest[x][3]);
      JButton button4 = new JButton();
      button4.setText(doneTest[x][4]);

      question.updateUI();
      panel.add(question);
      button1.updateUI();
      panel.add(button1);
      button2.updateUI();
      panel.add(button2);
      button3.updateUI();
      panel.add(button3);
      button4.updateUI();
      panel.add(button4);

      panel.revalidate();
      panel.repaint();
      frame.remove(panel);
      frame.add(panel);
      frame.revalidate();
      frame.repaint();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
      while(!button1.getModel().isPressed() || !button2.getModel().isPressed() || !button3.getModel().isPressed() || !button4.getModel().isPressed())
      {
        if(button1.getModel().isPressed())
        {
          System.out.println("Bt1");
          pressed = 1;
          break;
        }
        if(button2.getModel().isPressed())
        {
          System.out.println("Bt2");
          pressed = 2;
          break;
        }
        if(button3.getModel().isPressed())
        {
          System.out.println("Bt3");
          pressed = 3;
          break;
        }
        if(button4.getModel().isPressed())
        {
          System.out.println("Bt4");
          pressed = 4;
          break;
        }
      }
      button1.setVisible(false);
      button2.setVisible(false);
      button3.setVisible(false);
      button4.setVisible(false);
      question.setVisible(false);
    }

    return 999.99;
  }
```

That is my whole class that uses a JPanel / JFrame. My problem is is that every time it gets to the next question (next iteration in the `for loop`) it just doesn't redraw the buttons until mouseover and it also doesn't ever draw the new JLabel. Is this a problem with my code or a problem with JPanel itself? Sorry my code is so messy, I have been trying to find anyway to fix this and have abandoned cleanliness until it's complete.

Thank you guys for helping.

Comment: You appear to have a tight while loop, which is a very bad idea. You should revisit the whole design to be event-driven, which is how Swing is designed to be used. You can't write a Swing app handling input in the same way that you would a console app, for example.

Comment: I have yet to learn how to do JPanel formally, how would I do this event driven? I see the waitForEvent but I can't figure out how to do this.

Also, how does this differ from the while loop?

Comment: Event driven means get rid of the loop, and instead respond to events with listeners. How to use listeners is all well described in the Swing tutorials which you can find here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

Comment: OK, I will implement that. What can I do to fix the panels drawing weird?

Comment: It sounds like basically you should read a Swing tutorial as linked before. Don't try to fix your knowledge gaps piecemeal - it will be frustrating for you and everyone else.

Comment: Don't use the `updateUI()` method. A Swing component will repaint itself when a property of the component is changed.